# Recyclerview with LinearLayout cannot scroll

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

I will fill view by adapter and when iam fill data to RV then can not scroll.

This is my RC:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/trip_ticket_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/trip_ticket_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

RC is fill by this view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/TripMyTicketScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/my_ticket_port_and_directions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/grid_14"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/grid_2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/grid_2"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/grid_2"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/grid_2"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/grid_1"
        android:height="@dimen/grid_5"
        android:background="@color/bg_on_board_button"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_rudder_black_32dp"
        android:drawablePadding="6dp"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_rudder_black_32dp"
        android:gravity="center|start"
        android:padding="@dimen/grid_2"
        android:text="@string/my_ticket_port_and_direction"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_my_trip_button"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <include layout="@layout/view_my_trip_time_schedule" />

    <include layout="@layout/view_my_trip_passengers_and_cabins" />

    <include layout="@layout/view_my_trip_booking_number" />


</LinearLayout>
```

There are some linear layouts with buttons and textview in `<include layout=...`

And when view across the screen size then normally start scroll but in this case not. 
Adapter is empty for now because i have to solve this problem a them i will continue.

Can you help me? 
Thank you.

**Update**
This is RC init in Fragment

```
    private void initRecyclerView(){
        mAdapter = new MyTicketAdapter(getContext());
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerRv.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerRv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
```

Adapter does not fill any data for now. Here is adapter:

```
public class MyTicketAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyTicketAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private static final int BARCODE_IMAGE_WIDTH = 150;
    private static final int BARCODE_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 40;

    private Departure mDeparture;
    private final Context mContext;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
//
//        @BindView(R.id.my_ticket_booking_number_barcode_ticket)
//        ImageView mBarcodeImageView;
//
//        @BindView(R.id.my_ticket_booking_number_barcode_booking_number)
//        TextView mBookingNumberBelowBarcode;
//

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of this class.
     *
     * @param context need values from resource.
     */
    public MyTicketAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item_trip_ticket, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyTicketAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (mDeparture == null) {
            return;
        }

        TravelMateLogs.MY_TICKET_ADAPTER.i("--------Departure: " + mDeparture.toString());

   //     generateBarcode(holder);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        // There is only one item.
        if(mDeparture == null){
            return 0;
        }else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the data to be displayed in the list.
     *
     * @param departure The departure to be displayed in the view. Null will clear the list.
     */
    void setData(@Nullable Departure departure) {
        mDeparture = departure;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for a test case can u change android:layout_height="match_parent" to android:layout_height="wrap_content" for recyclerview item's LinearLayout and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I had to wrap all part to linearlayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/TripMyTicketScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/bg_trip_tab_view"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/grid_14">


        <include layout="@layout/view_my_trip_time_schedule" />

        <include layout="@layout/view_my_trip_passengers_and_cabins" />

        <include layout="@layout/view_my_trip_booking_number" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now it is work ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/trip_ticket_recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

If is wrap, recyclerview is not visible. Also please post recyclerview initialisation.